# makefile「'〇〇.a' に必要なターゲット '〇〇.o' を make するルールがありません. 」の原因が知りたい

Tags: c++, makefile

###### 質問内容

以下のmakefileですがエラーの原因がわかりません。なぜ`$(ALL_OBJ)`を`$(BINDIR)/%.o`で指定しているのに
以下のエラーが発生するのでしょうか？

###### 確認したこと

コンソールに変数の中身を出力
chatGPTで質問
./include/の各ディレクトリ内と./includeディレクトリにヘッダーファイル
./src/の各ディレクトリと./srcディレクトリ内にソースファイル
があることを確認

###### 参考サイト

make .phony https://yu-nix.com/archives/makefile-phony/#Makefile%E3%81%AEPHONY%E3%81%A7%E4%BE%BF%E5%88%A9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E3%81%8C%E5%A4%89%E3%82%8F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F
make 関数　https://tex2e.github.io/blog/makefile/functions

###### Error

```
$ make
ALL_SRC:  ./src/systems/WindowContext.cpp  ./src/utils/Shader.cpp  
ALL_OBJ: ./build/obj/WindowContext.o ./build/obj/Shader.o
make: *** 'build/lib/libFrameWork.a' に必要なターゲット 'build/obj/WindowContext.o' を make するルールがありません.  中止.
```

###### ディレクトリ構造

```
├── build
│   └── obj
│   └── lib
├── include
│   └── framework
│       ├── FrameWork.hpp
│       ├── components
│       ├── entities
│       ├── scenes
│       ├── systems
│       └── utils
├── resources
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── models
│   ├── shaders
│   └── textures
├── scripts
├── src
│   ├── components
│   ├── entities
│   ├── scenes
│   ├── systems
│   │   └── WindowContext.cpp
│   └── utils
│       └── Shader.cpp
└── test
```

###### makefile

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -O3
LDFLAGS=-lglfw -lGL -lGLEW

SRCDIR=./src
INCDIR=./include
BINDIR=./build/obj
DEPDIR=./build/obj
LIBDIR=./build/lib

ALL_SRC_DIR=$(shell find $(SRCDIR) -type d)
ALL_SRC_FLIES=$(wildcard $(ALL_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
ALL_SRC=$(foreach dir,$(ALL_SRC_DIR),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp))

ALL_OBJ=$(addprefix $(BINDIR)/, $(notdir $(ALL_SRC:.cpp=.o)))


DEP=$(ALL_OBJ:.o=.d)
INC=-I$(INCDIR)

TARGET=$(LIBDIR)/libFrameWork.a

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGET)


$(TARGET): $(ALL_OBJ)
    ar rcs $@ $^

$(BINDIR)/%.o: $(ALL_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -MMD -MP $< -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC)
-include $(DEP)


clean:
    rm -rf $(BINDIR)/* $(TARGET)


$(info ALL_SRC: $(ALL_SRC))
$(info ALL_OBJ: $(ALL_OBJ))
```

Comment: `$(ALL_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp` がどう展開されているか確認すれば理由はわかるかもしれません。

Comment: 原因かどうか分かりませんが、`$(BINDIR)/%.o:`から始まる3行の記述で、3行目に`-include $(DEP)`が行の先頭から単独で記述されているのはおかしいのでは？ その前の行にまとめるか、前の行の最後に行継続の指定をして`-include $(DEP)`はタブでインデントするところなのでは？ あるいは単に必要無い物が残っているだけかもしれませんが。

Comment: もしくはこの記事 [シンプルで応用の効くmakefileとその解説](http://urin.github.io/posts/2013/simple-makefile-for-clang) を見ると`-include $(DEP)`とその前の行の間に空行が必要なのかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ALL_SRC_DIR` にはおそらく `src/components src/entities src/scenes src/systems src/utils` というようなリストが入っているので、

```
$(BINDIR)/%.o: $(ALL_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
```

は

```
./build/obj/%.o: src/components src/entities src/scenes src/systems src/utils/%.cpp
```

と展開されます。このパターンは、ソースが `src/utils/` にあるときのみ適用されるので、`WindowContext.o` を作るルールが見つからないわけです。しかも `$<` は `src/components` なので何もコンパイルできません。

---

`$(BINDIR)/%.o` を作りたいときにソースがどこにあるか見つけなければなりません。3通りの解決法を紹介します。

##### 複数のパターンを用意する

```
$(BINDIR)/%.o: src/systems/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c ...
$(BINDIR)/%.o: src/utils/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c ...
```

のようにサブディレクトリ毎にパターンを書いておけば適切なものにマッチしてくれます。

##### ディレクトリ構造をマッチさせる

オブジェクトファイルもサブディレクトリに入れると話は簡単です。`ALL_OBJ` が `./build/obj/systems/WindowContext.o ./build/obj/utils/Shader.o` のようにサブディレクトリも入るようにすれば、`%` にサブディレクトリ名のマッチングも任せられるので、1つのパターンだけで済みます。

```
$(BINDIR)/%.o: src/%.cpp
    -/bin/mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) -c ...
```

##### [VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Directory-Search) で検索させる

make がファイルを探すときにカレントディレクトリ以外からも探すように指定できます。

```
VPATH=$(ALL_SRC_DIR)
$(BINDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c ...
```

Comment: 質問ですが、提示の解答には一行で行う方法がありませんがつまり一行で行うのは不可能ということでしょうか？

Comment: 質問文の条件では無理だと思います。私見ですが、一行で書けるかどうかは気にすることではないと思います。

Answer (score -2):

提示コードの

```
$(BINDIR)/%.o: $(ALL_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -MMD -MP $< -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC)
-include $(DEP)
```

部を

```
$(BINDIR)/%.o: $(ALL_SRC)
    $(CXX) -c -MMD -MP $< -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(INC)
-include $(DEP)
```

と編集して`make clean`したら

```
$ make
./build/obj/WindowContext.o ./build/obj/Shader.o
g++ -O3 -c -MMD -MP src/systems/WindowContext.cpp -o build/obj/WindowContext.o -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lglfw -lGLEW -lGL 
g++ -O3 -c -MMD -MP src/systems/WindowContext.cpp -o build/obj/Shader.o -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lglfw -lGLEW -lGL 
ar rcs build/lib/libFrameWork.a build/obj/WindowContext.o build/obj/Shader.o
```

と表示され成功しました。

Comment: それでは、Shader.cpp を編集すると、WIndowContext.cpp から Shader.o がビルドされるのでは。